# Terraform adding lambda layer

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to make terraform create a lambda layer and I am getting "Reference to undeclared resource"
Heres the main.tf code in the src directory where I get the error

```
module "name" {
  ...
  ...
  layer_arns = [aws_lambda_layer_version.mm_layer.arn]
  ...
  ...
}
```

Heres the lambda-layer.tf resource file inside a lambda-layer folder that I am trying to reference

```
locals {
  region = var.region
}

resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "mm_layer" {
  layer_name = "common-layer"
  ...
  ...
  compatible_runtimes = ["nodejs12.x"]
}
```

EDIT: Heres the declared module

```
module "lambda-layer" {
  source = "./modules/lambda-layer"
  region = module.common.region[module.common.region]
  env = var.env
}
```

Not sure why it cannot find the reference. I clearly state it in resource that is it mm_layer, and I try to call it as "mm_layer"

Comment: "the lambda-layer.tf resource file inside a lambda-layer folder" implies that resource is in a declared module. If so, please add that module declaration to the question.

Comment: Added in the edit.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `aws_lambda_layer_version.mm_layer` is not in the declared outputs for the `lambda-layer` module?

Comment: So I added an output.tf and declared this: output "aws_lambda_layer_version_mm_layer" {
  value = aws_lambda_layer_version.mm_layer.arn
}
 I am still getting the same error though. Pretty sure I delcared it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After determining that the declared resourced is in a declared module, and that the resource's exported attributes are absent from the module's declared outputs, we can solve this by declaring the exported attribute as an output for the declared module. This is because exported resource attributes exist only within the same config namespace, and must be accessed using the namespace nomenclature.

Inside the config for the `lambda-layer` module source, you need to add a declared output:

```
output "mm_layer_arn" {
  description = "arn for the mm lambda layer"
  value       = aws_lambda_layer_version.mm_layer.arn
}
```

You can similarly output the entire object of exported resource attributes by assigning `aws_lambda_layer_version.mm_layer` to the value, but this is mostly useful if you need to access or otherwise iterate on that object.

This output will now be accessible from the namespace of the config where the module (in this situation `lambda-layer`) is declared. Since module `name` is declared in the same config as the `lambda-layer` declaration, that module declaration can now access the output in the appropriate namespace:

```
module "name" {
  ...
  layer_arns = [module.lambda-layer.mm_layer_arn]
  ...
}
```

You can read more about module output namespace in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/outputs.html#accessing-child-module-outputs).